# Advanced Galois theory/field theory book suggestions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, book-recommendation

I have done the equivalent of an undergraduate algebra course(rings/fields/groups) and have read Stewart's Galois theory book. Galois theory was a lot of fun and I would like to continue studying it but I have no idea how to progress studying it or what the big theorems/questions further are.

I would like any suggestions on books that extend basic galois theory. All the suggestions  I can find are at the level of Stewart's book(ie. end with essentially a proof of the insolubility of the quintic).

Comment: There is some deeper Galois theory in Isaac's Algebra. His treatment culminates in the Artin-Schrier theorem, which says that when the algebraic closure of a field is a finite degree extension, then it is very similar to the extension $|C:R|$. Another neat topic Galois theoretic topic is Hilbert's ramification theory, which you can find treated in the first (extremely dense) chapter of Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory. I would recommend reading the sections on Galois theory and commutative algebra in Isaac's before reading Neukirch, since some of the basic exposition in Neukirch is lacking.

Comment: Galois theory is a major underpinning of algebraic number theory as a whole, so you might like to go on to see a broader slice of that subject. I recommend all of J.S. Milne's course notes for number theory and algebraic geometry from the level you're already at through topics like etale cohomology that are rarely lectured.

Answer (score 1):

Galois groups are precisely the profinite groups. I recommend giving Wilson's book on profinite groups a look, and slowly you can make your way to reading Serre's Galois Cohomology.

Comment: just noticed this is a very old question ha..

Answer (score 0):

You can try Theory of Commutative Fields By M. Nagata